# How to upload a .data-00000-of-00001 using github lfs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, git-lfs

I want to upload my tensorflow saved files to github. But the .datadata-00000-of-00001 file is almost 55 mb and github allows only 25 mb size. I tried using git lfs. But I dont understand what to give for this command.:

```
git lfs track "*.psd"
```

Do I give .data-00000-of-00001 as the file extension? But its saying not a git repository. Im really new to this. Can anyone tell me how to upload this into my github repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub upload limit is 25 MB only when uploading through a browser. If you push to your repository using git (either through command line or a git client), [you can upload files upto 100 MB in size](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota).

Comment: It is now 50 mb limit not 100 mb.

Comment: You get a [warning](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files) while going above 50 MB, but it still allows you to push files up to 100 MB in size.